# Динамический задний фон Activity в приложении Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Здравствуйте. Требуется реализовать Activity с некой разметкой (Кнопки, текстовые поля и т.д.) но с динамически меняющимся фоном (Background), скажем отображение анимации или отрисовка изменяющейся графики. То есть организовать как бы двухслойное Activity, чтобы сзади происходили всякие декоративные вещи, а поверх элементы управления. Какими средствами реализуется подобное? Заранее спасибо за любые варианты.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Необходимо использовать

```
<FrameLayout ...>
    <View [на котором происходит отрисовка] ... />
    <LinearLayout ...> Содиржимое страницы (кнопки и прочее) </LinearLayout> 
</FrameLayout>
```

В качестве `View` можно использовать `ImageView` с ресурсом `AnimationDrawable` или `VideoView` или что-то своё.

Comment: На сколько я понимаю, `FrameLayout` может содержать только один дочерний элемент, так что кто-то из нас не прав :)

Comment: Видимо вы. Скорее всего вы путаете со ScrollView или чем то ещё

Comment: А как вы делаете так, чтобы отображались все дочерние элементы, а не самый последний поверх остальных?

Comment: ну у вас ведь в LinearLayout фон прозрачный будет, соответственно все кнопки и другие контролы будут видны поверх нижних слоёв

Comment: Тогда прокатит:) Но это лучше в своем ответе указать явно.

Comment: Вот это попробуем. Отпишу, как протестирую

Comment: Спасибо большое!!! Вот это то, что доктор прописал. Загружаю в файл анимации отрендеренные кадры 3-D графики. На выходе: чудесная объемная анимация задним фоном за кнопками!

Answer (score 2):

Опишу решение (возможное), как его вижу, хотя не совсем понято, что конкретно вас смущает и что именно нужно. И так, вы создаете макет с главным контейнерным элементом (`LinearLayout` или `RelativeLayout`). Далее Вы можете в зависимости от условий менять фон либо корневого элемента, используя методы `setBackgroungDrawable`, `setBackgroundResource` или `setBackgroundColor`. В корневой элемент вы можете добавить вьюшку (абсолютно любую) и применять к ней анимации. Для эстетов извращений можно использовать OpenGL.

Далее вы вкладываете внутрь той вьюшки свои элементы управления. Как-то так!

Comment: "вкладываете внутрь той вьюшки свои элементы управления."
С этого момента поподробнее, пожалуйста. Как это? Я могу всунуть в свой кастомный View стандартные элементы Button, Spinner и т.д.? Есть какой-то пример в виде xml-разметки или это делается в описании класса View-наследника? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Конечно! Если вы свой кастомный вью наследуете от ViewGroup или одного из Лэйаутов, то можете. Например вот: http://code.google.com/p/iosched/source/browse/android/src/com/google/android/apps/iosched/ui/widget/DashboardLayout.java